# clickhouse how to update json field

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to update a field named `source` in a json column calling `message` in Clickhouse by the following:

```
ALTER TABLE mynamespace.mytable
UPDATE message.source= NULL
WHERE web_id='xxx' and 
equals(message.source,'test')
```

But I recieve the following error:

> Code: 62. DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 76 ('.') (line 2, col 15): .source= NULL
> WHERE web_id='xxx' and
> equals(message.source,'test'). Expected one of: token, Equals. (SYNTAX_ERROR) (version 22.6.7.7 (official build))

```
CREATE TABLE mynamespace.mytable
(
    `web_id` String,
    timestamp DateTime,
    message JSON
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY (wi,uid)
```

How can I update a json field in Clickhouse.

Answer (score 0):

Let's please take a look at the table definition for "mynamespace.mytable" - is the column "message" a ClickHouse Nested structure? https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/nested-data-structures/nested

Could do this to show us table DDL:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mynamespace.mytable;
```

Or perhaps an example of the values in the "message" column:

```
SELECT message.source
FROM mynamespace.mytable
WHERE web_id='xxx';
```

Using ALTER TABLE...UPDATE for Nested data structures has some limitations, as noted in the Docs:

```
The ALTER query for elements in a nested data structure has limitations.
```

Thanks

Comment: I add the structure of the table. It's not a nested field.